# How to test PHP send mail on local server with MAMP Pro

Tags: php, email, sendmail, dreamweaver, mamp-pro

I have a small web form that on submission triggers a mail script that sends an email to the address given to verify their email address.

I want to test this on my local server using MAMP Pro. I am totally confused from the info I have sourced that holds different advice and requirements.

I use Dreamweaver (DW) with WebAssist (WA) extensions to build my PHP scripts and when I contacted WA support to ask how to enter the correct settings with their DW plugin to work with MAMP pro they told me..

> To have your localhost send email you need to install a local SMTP server configured for email relay.
>
> If you want to use a remote smtp server you would likely have to use the PEAR mail option for authentication.

This has thrown me as I can't see anywhere in any MAMP Pro documentation about having to install SMTP servers and I know nothing about PEARL.

The following Blog makes it sound simple..

http://blog-en.mamp.info/2009/09/how-to-sending-emails-with-mamp-pro.html

But it obviously isn't as I have tried these Postfix settings with know joy.

I have also seen this post..

[Test emails locally with mamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30616766/test-emails-locally-with-mamp)

..that gives a method using gmail but I just can't make sense of it as It appears that the MAMP interface may have changed since this was written.

Plus I am not familiar with using Terminal.

If anyone can shed some light on this to point me in the right direction I would be most greatfull

Comment: I use an app call test Mail Server Tool (http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/) start it up, send emails --- easy

Comment: Thanks @jeff I'll check it out.

Comment: Sorry @jeff I should have made it clearer. I am working on a Mac, your suggestion is a windows application.

Answer (score 7):

You can use Mailhog to achieve this. I wrote a [tutorial on Medium](https://medium.com/@janhenkes/setup-mailhog-with-mamp-pro-to-catch-outgoing-emails-4c20778642c3).

Install mailhog using Homebrew (if you don't have Homebrew installed, check out the instructions here: https://brew.sh/):

```
brew install mailhog
```

Open MAMP Pro and go to the “Postfix” tab. Make sure the checkbox next to “Include Postfix service in GroupStart” is checked.
Use these setting for Postfix:

1. Fill in your domain name in the field “Set domain of outgoing e-mails to:”
2. Check “Use a Smart host for routing”
3. “Server name:” is 127.0.0.1:1025 (this is the SMTP port Mailhog uses)
4. Set “Authentication” to “none”

Go to http://127.0.0.1:8025/ in your browser to see the mails sent by PHP.

Comment: Thanks for this @janhenkes. Will check it out when I get the time

Comment: @huykon225, you need to start mailhog via:  brew services start mailhog

Comment: Here's an updated way to configure Mailhog with MampPro. https://gist.github.com/jaredatch/2574941e8ff480942f82a1a4c22f0678